# Power off screen - i do not know how to continue

Tags: java, android, adb, screen, reboot

I'm working on an app (JobService) that should restart the device once a week using an ADB command (from the code). This works very well. Background: The device is used for navigation and is permanently supplied with voltage and switched on. The navigation app hangs after several weeks and requires a restart. The problem now is that after the restart the display is on and is kept awake by another application. I can only turn this off by pressing the power button. Android version is 6.0.1. Since there are many devices, the restart should be automated.

I have now pursued and tested many thoughts, unfortunately without success:

- Internal code ADB command: "input keyevent 26"
- Internal code ADB command: "sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 116 0"
- Various options without ADB:

```
 mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
 mWakeLock.acquire();
```

```
DevicePolicyManager manager = ((DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE));
manager.lockNow();
```

Solutions with brightness or a black overlay are not practical. There are many possibilities in these forms, but none of them worked. ADB only works when sent from the computer. Root is not available or unfortunately no option.

Comment: It's not clear what you have or want, you first mention "an ADB command" but then you give the impression that you don't have a computer connected to the device.

Comment: I need a solution that can be run by the app itself. I also tried executing various ADB commands from the code. "Reboot" works with it, but not turning off the screen. However, this works when I send the command via ADB from the PC. This means that the command itself works, just not from the app.